# Using namespaces in lxml

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I am trying to do svg parsing with `lxml` and struggle with namespaces.

Questions:

1. How do I iterate over all `image` tags, with `tree.iterfind` and a namsepace map? `tree.iterfind('image', root.nsmap)` does not retun anything, the uglier `tree.iter('{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}image')` works
2. I am trying to turn `image` tags into `use` tags. While lxml gives me an attribute dictionary with `xlinx:href` it chokes on passing this to `makeelement` is there an elegant solution?
3. Should I use `lxml` or is there something better (more straight forward)? My goal is to rewrite `image` tags to `use` tags and embed the content of the referenced svgs in symbols. (So far `lxml` and the issues I had with namespaces seem repulsive).

.

```
from lxml import etree

def inlineSvg(path):
    parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
    tree = etree.parse(path, parser)

    root = tree.getroot()
    print(root.nsmap)


    for img in tree.iter('{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}image'):
    #for img in tree.iterfind('image', root.nsmap): #for some reason I can't get this to work...
        print(img)

        #we have to translate xlink: to {http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink} for it to work, despit the lib returning xlink: ...
        settableAttributes = dict(img.items()) #img.attribute
        settableAttributes['{http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}href'] = settableAttributes['xlink:href']
        del settableAttributes['xlink:href']

        print(etree.tostring(img.makeelement('use', settableAttributes)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - How do I iterate over all image tags, with tree.iterfind and a namsepace map?

```
for img in root.iterfind('image', namespaces=root.nsmap):
```

> - I am trying to turn image tags into use tags. While lxml gives me an attribute dictionary with xlinx:href it chokes on passing this to makeelement is there an elegant solution?

Either of these works for me:

```
img.makeelement('use', dict(img.items())
img.makeelement('use', img.attrib)
```

> - Should I use lxml or is there something better (more straight forward)?

Everybody's got an opinion. I like lxml. I find it very straightforward. Your opinion may differ.

---

Complete program:

```
from lxml import etree

def inlineSvg(path):
    parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
    tree = etree.parse(path, parser)

    root = tree.getroot()

    for img in root.iterfind('image', namespaces=root.nsmap):
        use = img.makeelement('use', img.attrib, nsmap=root.nsmap)
        print(etree.tostring(use))

inlineSvg('xx.svg')
```

Input file (`xx.svg`):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <rect x="10" y="10" height="130" width="500" style="fill: #000000"/>

  <image x="20" y="20" width="300" height="80"
     xlink:href="http://jenkov.com/images/layout/top-bar-logo.png" />

  <line x1="25" y1="80" x2="350" y2="80"
            style="stroke: #ffffff; stroke-width: 3;"/>
</svg>
```

result:

```
$ python xx.py 
b'<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="80" width="300" x="20" y="20" xlink:href="http://jenkov.com/images/layout/top-bar-logo.png"/>'
```

Reference:

- http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#iterfind
- http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/image-element.html#svg-image-example

Comment: Great general Answer. I think the problem why `img.makeelement('use', img.attrib)` does not work for me, is that my svg file misses `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`. Is there any way I can add this?

Comment: Perhaps. Please edit your question to include a short, complete SVG file that demonstrates the error.

Comment: For the moment I have solved my issue using `etree.register_namespace('xlink','http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')`. As some of my issues might be related to `pip` vs `yum` on centos (potentialy the dynamic library might have the wrong version) I think there is not much point in diving deeper into this. If you however are still interested, have a look at this [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/109242/121183) and [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/109264/121183). It contains a minimal example svg, and is the reason for looking into etree, the answer is the result

Comment: As the script does the job, I am only half keen to find a better way to find a better way to insert namespaces (as my solution is ugly hardcoded).